# How to optimise nested for loops in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, compiler-optimization

I have the following code:

```
for j in range(repetitions):
    for i in range(nof_sweep_points):
        for k in range(syncs_per_sweep_point):
            joint_mask = np.array(sync_mask == i) & np.array(rep_mask == j)
            channel_deltas = t2_data.channel_time_since_sync[channel_str][joint_mask]                    
            (channel_hist[j][i][k], _) = np.histogram(channel_deltas, np.arange(bin_start, bin_stop + 1))
```

but my code keeps crashing when I increase the size of `repetitions` and `nof_sweep_points`. How can I avoid nested for loops?
For reference:
t2_data is a class that contains some arrays like channel_time_since_sync[channel_str] that has shape (x,).
sync_mask and rep_mask are arrays of shape (x,) as well. The elements of these arrays are picked from 0 to `nof_sweep_points` and from 0 to `repetitions`, respectively

Comment: What is it you want to achieve exactly? It looks like you can use `numpy` to operate on the matrix at once which is a huge optimization.

Comment: I need to populate channel_hist which has dimensions (repetitions, nof_sweep_points, sync_per_sweep_point) according to the masks in the lines before

Comment: Have you looked at [`numpy.histogramdd`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html)?

Comment: How can I avoid the for-loops for channel_deltas then?

Comment: Can you not make construct this array at once as well? I cannot really answer that without the full code (what is t2_data? what do your matrices look like?). Please provide a minimal standalone piece of code first.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: you can start by converting range into iterators  this will improve/help in problem with crashing